# Enumerating document names in citrix sessions

Tags: automation, citrix

Both Excel and Word applications are published on Citrix XenApp server. My users are accessing both excel and word documents via Citrix sessions. I wish to print the names of documents that are opened currently in their sessions programmatic ally. Does anybody have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should still be able to access the document names via the window caption since the Citrix client includes the caption of the app on the server in it's own caption. As an example I'm running Excel published via Citrix and it shows the window caption as:

Test Document.xlsx - Excel - \\Remote

So with some parsing you should be able to extract the document name, i.e. "Test Document.xlsx" in my example.

Comment: Thanks Donovan. I found the same thing couple of days back and saw your answer today.